# Robertson/Square drive uses/sizes?

Tags: tools, bits

I'm in the market for some bits for Robertson/Square drive fasteners.

I noticed one set has sizes SQ2.5 and SQ2.7, in addition to the more normal whole number sizes.

What are these two odd ball sizes associated with, or used for?

What are the bit/tip dimensions for them?

Added a Wikipedia table for the screw recess dims.[image]

Comment: I'd venture to say they're for 2.5 and 2.7 sized screws...

Comment: As a cynic would say someone goof up making them and instead of tossing them, added them to sets and jack up the price.  Can barely see the difference in size between #2 and #3.

Comment: Link to product?  Maybe those are the length of the bits in inches.   Maybe translation or printing errors.  Maybe useless extra bits included to get the set up to 100 pieces or however many it has.

Comment: @jay613  Google does show a few bit sets with those sizes, so guess it is a thing.  Maybe special size for something no one uses.

Comment: After considerable further thought and research, I believe @FreeMan has come about as close as we'll get.  You could say he's nailed it, but that seems inappropriate.

Comment: More likely, I've screwed up, as usual, @jay613!

Comment: those are sizes in mm ... my #2 Robertson bit measures 2.7 mm ... the 2.5 mm bit would still be a #2 bit

Comment: @jsotola That's interesting. So the "special" bits in the bundle are basically "duplicates". I bet they are not even made that way but are "rejects" at a measuring/quality step and then just added back into the bundle to "fill it out". Thanks everyone - if anyone learns something more definitive, jump back in here.

Comment: @jsotola Did your bit have the well-known taper on the tip?